# Post value from an input added by jQuery's .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to POST values inserted on an Input that has been added to screen by jQuery's `.html` method. I need to first store those values on variables, and my problem is that variables are sent empty, as any alert made of these gives undefined result. Here's an exaple of one of those:

```
var turnIdEdit = $('.acceptIcon').attr('id');
```

This is being taken from an entire div inserted by `.html` method, and I do not know how to express this value storation in order to make jQuery search on DOM's existing parent (before html insertion) for this '.acceptIcon' class.

I have tried to ask jQuery to search on `'.tablecontent'` (that exists before the html insertion, and is one of `'.acceptIcon'`s parents) without result:

```
var turnIdEdit = $('.tableContent', '.acceptIcon').attr('id');
```

How can I store values from inputs generated by jQuery's .html method on variables?

ADITIONAL INFO--

This is the execution of the function that njects the HTML inpts:

```
$('.tableIconLink').on('click', '.editIcon', editRow);
var optionList = "<?php echo $all_turns; ?>";
```

This is the function that injects this HTML piece:

```
function editRow(e){
    var recordId = $(this).attr('id');
    var textId = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).parents().eq(3).html("<div class='contentColumn60'><span class='tableContentText'><input type='text' class='tableEditInput' id='"+recordId+"' name='tu_name_edit' value='"+textId+"'></span></div><div class='contentColumn20'><span class='tableContentText'><select id='tu_type' class='tableEditOption' name='tu_type_edit'>"+optionList+"</select></span></div><div class='contentColumn10'><span class='tableHeaderText'>Editando</span></div><div class='contentColumn10'><div class='acceptEdit'><a href='#'><div class='acceptIcon' id='"+recordId+"'></div></a></div></div>");
    e.preventDefault;
}
```

And this is the entire DOM initial tree (before HTM injection):

```
<div class="tableContent">
<div id="225" class="tableRow ">
                        <div class="contentColumn60">
                            <span class="tableContentText">Intensivo semanal (09:00 - 19:30)</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contentColumn20">
                            <span class="tableContentText">Turnos intensivos</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contentColumn10">
                            <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="#"><div title="Intensivo semanal (09:00 - 19:30)" id="225" class="editIcon"></div></a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contentColumn10">
                            <div class="tableIconLink"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=225"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
</div>
```

After making the HTML input injection:

```
    <div class="tableContent">
    <div id="225" class="tableRow ">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">
    <input id="225" class="tableEditInput" type="text" value="Intensivo semanal (09:00 - 19:30)" name="tu_name_edit">
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn20">
    <span class="tableContentText">
    <select id="tu_type" class="tableEditOption" name="tu_type_edit">
    <option value="">Mañana</option>
    <option value="">Tarde</option>
    <option value="">Noche</option>
    <option value="">Turnos intensivos</option>
    <option value="">Fines de semana</option>
    </select>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
    <span class="tableHeaderText">Editando</span>
    </div>
    <div class="contentColumn10">
    <div class="acceptEdit">
    <a href="#">
    <div id="225" class="acceptIcon"></div>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how does your HTML look like?

Comment: Hard to understand, could you show your HTML result ?

Comment: Now correct piece added.

Comment: two `id` with the same value ? not good. You could use [`data-attributes`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the value.

Comment: Even when I am almost sure this ID duplicity is not causing the problem, why is it recomended not to have similar ID's?

Comment: i did not even know about those atributes. That is fantastc. Thank you vey much Mama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your edit I removed the first part to this answer, since it does look like you are looking for the `id` attribute and not the inner html of the node.

For the selector issue, I think you want to change `$('.tableContent', '.acceptIcon')` to `$('.tableContent .acceptIcon')`.  This is using css selector syntax for jQuery to select all nodes that have the `acceptIcon` class, which exist inside an element with the `tableContent` class.

```
var turnIdEdit = $('.tableContent .acceptIcon').attr('id');
```

Keep in mind that if there are multiple elements inside the `.tableContent` element with the `acceptIcon` class, this will not give the expected result and you will need to narrow the selector to isolate the element you are looking for.

Comment: Hi WIll. Thank you for your attention. I have changed by **var turnIdEdit = $('.tableContent, .acceptIcon').attr('id');** and variable value stills undefined.

Comment: @Biomehanika I'm also not seeing the `.tableContent` element in your html, can you add that in it's relative location since it's part of your selector?

Comment: var turnIdEdit = $('.tableContent .acceptIcon').attr('id');
 neither works. I'll post entire HTML, one minute

Comment: Added on question. Everything except .tableContent div is injected by jQuery .html() method. Thank you will.

Comment: @Biomehanika There must be another issue as gibberish points out it would be useful to see how the function that assigns that variable is called, see this fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hJArv/

Comment: Hi Will. About your last edit, there is only one acceptIcon div.

Comment: I am about to post that function. Thank you

Comment: ADDED. Have in mind this function works perfectly, and html is injected fine. The problem is when trying to extract info on that html inputs.

Comment: @Biomehanika Right, that's the function, when is this called and the turnIdEdit variable populated?

Comment: This is called before storing values on the variable. Here you have the exact order: http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/6442/eyok.png

Comment: @Biomehanika it looks like you are trying to grab the value before the click event is triggered which creates the elements.  If so you will need to get the value in a different way.

Comment: Hi Will, at least @gibberish solved this, thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be your problem, but it is a common error when using the `.html()` method, so worth mentioning.

The `.html()` method changes the DOM, so event bindings are not in place for the new elements injected by `.html()`. Therefore, one must use the `.on()` method to attach new event bindings to those methods.

You haven't mentioned what triggers the code to grab the `.acceptIcon`'s ID attribute, so perhaps this is what's going on.

For example:

```
$('#anInjectedDiv').click(function() {
    alert('I am in the DIV');
});
```

Must be written this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '#anInjectedDiv', function() {
    alert('I am in the DIV');
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bFWd2/)</kbd> added per question in comments

Comment: Hi gibberish. Thank you for your attention. I do know that, as to execute first function a click must be done in an injected element. And for that I had to set it this way: ** $('.tableContent').on('click', '.acceptIcon', insertEditRow);
** BUT I do not know how to store values introduced on inputs that have been injected, as jQuery does not recognise them as objects. Do you know hoy could I?

Comment: Actually, jQuery does recognize them as objects and you should be able to grab the field value the same way as usual. [Here is a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bFWd2/). Note that one button grabs the value from the injected input field and the other does not -- but the code to grab the value is the same. The difference is how the event is captured.

Comment: I am very grateful for your effort. This is the solution. Defining variables inside the executed function. One hundred thanks @gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code is helpful, thanks for adding that.

Try this to get the desired DIV's ID:

```
var turnIdEdit = $('.tableContent').find('.acceptEdit').find('.acceptIcon').attr('id');
```

If this doesn't help, you may have to show us more of your DOM tree so that we can ensure we are grabbing a specific element. Usually, we want to begin a DOM traversal with an element identified by ID to ensure there can be only one (and not several elements returned, as can happen with classes). Will P first made this valid point (+1 for him).

I usually run a series of tests to ensure that I am where I think I should be. This works best by adding ID attributes (even temporarily, for testing), such as:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tableContent" id="yupthisone">
    <div class="contentColumn60">
    <span class="tableContentText">
    <input id="225" class="tableEditInput" type="text" value="Intensivo semanal (09:00 - 19:30)" name="tu_name_edit">
    </span>
    </div>

    <div class="acceptEdit" id="therightplace">
    <a href="#">
    <div id="225" class="acceptIcon" id="finallyfoundit"></div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
var d1 = $('.tableContent').attr('id');
alert(d1);

var d2 = $('.tableContent').find('.acceptEdit').attr('id');
alert(d2);

var d3 = $('.tableContent').find('.acceptEdit').find('.acceptIcon').attr('id');
alert(d3);
```

Comment: I was going to develop your last solution till I read this. I have tried this and alert from turnIdEdit stills give me undefined. If .find method should be working properly, what could be failing? I am about to post the entire DIV initial structure. 1 min pls

Comment: I have added to the question a more complete piece of HTML tree, as I guess the correct method that shoul work is .find In any case your last solution does work, but if you want to investigate about this, just great.

Comment: @Biomehanika See additional ideas for future use added to answer above

Comment: @Biomehanika Studying the larger HTML (injected data), please note that you have two divs with the identical ID. IDs should always be unique in the DOM. First thing to fix!

Comment: I am about to try the best way to get this values. Thank you for your attention. About Id's, yes, that's right, in deed I have just known abou the existance of data-atribtes in HTML5 to store any kind of data I need, everything will be stored on a data-id atribute or similar

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you have three elements containing the same id:

```
line 02 - <div id="225" class="tableRow ">
line 05 - <input id="225" class="tableEditInput" type="text" value="Intensivo etc.">
line 25 - <div id="225" class="acceptIcon">
```

There must be only one element containing the ID "255". The ID attribute must always be unique in the DOM.

What I usually do, is add a prefix to the desired id value. For example: `id="tr-225"`, `id="tEI-225"`, `id="aI-225"` (or, any ONE of them may remain as just `id="225"`, but only one).

If required, I can isolate just the numerical bit by splitting off the first part:

```
 var justTheID = $('.tableRow).attr('id').split('-')[1];
 alert(justTheID);
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Expanded Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bFWd2/1/)</kbd>

Note that the `split()` method splits the string into an array, separating elements at the character you supply. We supply the `-` character, so the string is split into two parts at that character, with element zero being the left half, and element one being the number part. (There is only one `-` char in the string, so only two elements are created in this particular array.)

**Resources:**

[programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really#answer-127180)

[W3C Working Draft - HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html) - search for keyword "unique"

Comment: That is a very good method. I did replace all "ID" atributes by data-id, so that the ID value is stored there and there seems not to be any conflict between Id's, and seems to work fine. how do you feel about this?

Comment: A quick google does not show that data- attributes require unique values, so you should be good there. [Here is a good SO answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really#answer-127180) re duplicate ID values -- the first comment notes that if IDs are duplicated on the page you may receive **`undefined`** when requesting one of the IDs. *Perhaps that was what you experienced?*

Comment: I don't think ID dupicity was the reason for my problem, as before applying your function inner variables solution (which works perfectly!), I changed all ID for DATA-ID and the problem remained. Now it is solved, working and with no id duplicity. Thank you gibberish.